# how do I overwrite text I've already written to the console?

Tags: python

I am trying to get this to

1. Read the text from screen           #Working
2. Output the text                     #Working
3. Delete Output                       #Not working
4. Replace with Output every 5 second. #Not working as depended on prior

Can someone help?

I am trying to get this algo to read the screen every 5 seconds, but it seems to only do it once.

Any suggestions?

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
import io
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

with mss.mss() as mss_instance:
    mon = mss_instance.monitors[0]
    screenshot = mss_instance.grab(mon)

with mss.mss() as sct:
    while True:
        im = numpy.asarray(sct.grab(mon))
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
        plt.show()
        print(text)

        
        time.sleep(5)                          # One screenshot per 5 seconds
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        continue
```

Comment: Why do you think this is not working?

Comment: what's the point of the `continue`?

Comment: @TimRoberts My best guess is that I have not given it the right incentive to reset and repeat

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Was thinking that is would continue to repeat the script, but I am probably wrong

Comment: `continue` just says to go back to the top of the `while` loop, which it would do anyway even if the `continue` was not there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see my question was ambiguous.  What I meant is, what is this NOT doing that you wanted it to do?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the feedback and you are perfectly right. 
My remaining questions is still how to clear the output "text" and create a new output "text" every 5 seconds?

Read the "text" from screen                   #Is working
Output "text"                                          #Is working
Delete/clear output "text"                      #Not working  
Replace with Output every 5 second.    #Not working as depended on prior

Answer (score 1):

So, your question really is "how to I overwrite text I've already written to the console?"   There are two ways.

If there is only one line of text, just write a carriage return at the end instead of a newline.  For example:

```
    print(text, end='\r')
```

If there are multiple lines of text, you can clear the screen before writing:

```
    os.system('cls')
    print(text)
```

Note that "cls" is specifically for Windows, which is what you are using.  If you intend this to be used on other operating systems, you would need something like:

```
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Oh no, just realized that this may not work since I am using Jyputer Notebook. Any advise?

Comment: So, you haven't even tried it?

Comment: Sorry bad English, I used your feedback, but it keeps on adding additional output over and over, so it does not clear the output before adding new. 

My comment was only to suggest a reason why your suggestion was not working.

Comment: Just moved the code to VScode and it works perfectly. Thank you.